# How to show that this set is closed in this strange topology on the space of probability measures?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ and $\mathcal P$ the space of all probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. We consider the topology on $\mathcal P$ generated by sets of the form

$$U(P, \mathcal{A}, \varepsilon)=\left\{P^{\prime} \in \mathcal{P}:\left|P^{\prime}\left(A_{i}\right)-P\left(A_{i}\right)\right|<\varepsilon, i=1, \ldots, k\right\}$$

with $\mathcal{A}=\left(A_{1}, \ldots, A_{k}\right)$ a partition of $\Omega, P \in \mathcal{P}$ et $\varepsilon>0$.

This topology is called $\tau$-topology, I am not very familiar with it.

Now choose $\Omega=C[0,1]$, $\mathcal F$ the Borelian $\sigma$-algebra on $C[0,1]$. Fix two probability measures on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$, $P_0, P_1$ and consider the set $\Gamma=\{P \in \mathcal P : P \text{ has marginals } P_0, P_1 \text{ at times } 0,1 \text{ respectively}\}$.

I would like to show that $\Gamma$ is closed in $\mathcal P$ for the $\tau$ topology. Any idea ?

Comment: It;'s a pretty standard weak topology. We see the set measures as subsets of a product $\mathbb{R}^\Omega$ and consider the subspace topology induced from the product topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q \in \mathcal P \backslash \Omega$. Assume wlog that the marginal $Q_0$ of $Q$ at $0$  is different from $P_0$. There is a borellian $B \in \mathcal B$ such that $Q_0(B) \neq P_0(B)$. Let $\varepsilon = |Q_0(B) - P_0(B)|>0$.

Let $A = \{ f\in \Omega : f(0) \in B \}$. Then if $Q' \in U(Q,\{A,A^c\}, \varepsilon)$, we have :
$$|Q_0'(B)-Q_0(B)| = |Q'(A) - Q(A)|< \varepsilon$$

so $Q_0'(B) \neq P_0(B)$.

Then $U(Q,\{A,A^c\}, \varepsilon) \subset \mathcal P \backslash \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is closed.